# How to create a plot with time series xaxis descending order?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a time series plot with matplotlib, and making the xaxis with descending time. Like to reverse the figure below and make the xaxis starting from Aug-18 and ending on Aug-10.

Is there any way to do this?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use decreasing axes by flipping the normal order of the axis limits

```
plt.xlim(datetime.max(), datetime.min())
```